# Check Revision of GIT file with Python

Tags: python, git

Lets say I have a file located at:

```
    'C:/Users/jdoe/development/git/something/A.txt'
```

I want to define a Python function that will check if that file is inside of a git repo.  If it is not in a git repo, I want the function to return None.  If it is in a git repo, I want the function to return the status of the file as well as the file revision.

```
    def git_check(path):
         if path is not in a git repo:
             return None
         else:
             return (status, last_clean_revision)
```

I'm not sure whether I should pursue GitPython option or subprocess.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Definitely go with GitPython: it should allow working with Git more directly, rather than parsing the output of a command line tool.

Answer (score 0):

From seeing the source code it seems GitPython uses subprocess anyway.

I would stick to using GitPython to prevent yourself the headache of parsing output text from git.

As far as guidance goes, there does not seem to be much documentation so I just suggest you read the source code itself which seems to be well commented.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going the subprocess route.  I didn't like having to set up a repo object first with GitPython, because there was no guarantee my path was even part of a git repository.

For those interested, here is what I ended up with:

```
import subprocess

def git_check(path):  # haha, get it?
    # check if the file is in a git repository
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['git',
                             'rev-parse',
                             '--is-inside-work-tree',],
                             cwd = path,
                             stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    if 'true' not in proc.communicate()[0]:
        return None

    # check the status of the repository
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['git',
                             'status',],
                             cwd = path,
                             stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    log_lines = proc.communicate()[0].split('\n')
    modified_files = [x.split(':')[1].lstrip() for x in log_lines if 'modified' in x]
    new_files = [x.split(':')[1].lstrip() for x in log_lines if 'new file' in x]

    # get log information
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['git',
                             'log','-1'],
                             cwd = path,
                             stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)         
    log_lines = proc.communicate()[0].split('\n')
    commit = ' '.join(log_lines[0].split()[1:])
    author = ' '.join(log_lines[1].split()[1:])
    date = ' '.join(log_lines[2].split()[1:])


    git_info = {'commit':commit,
                'author':author,
                'data': date,
                'new files':new_files,
                'modified files':modified_files}

    return git_info
```